# Expanding an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm a Java programer lost in C++ and pointers :D

I have an array of pointers to Bucket-Objects

```
Bucket<E>* index = new Bucket<E>[2];
```

I initialize it like this:

```
index[0] points to Bucket1
index[1] points to Bucket2
```

And then I want to double the size of the array and link the additional entries like this:

```
index[0] points to Bucket1
index[1] points to Bucket2
index[2] points to Bucket1
index[3] points to Bucket2
```

I have this code so far, which generates copies of the Bucket-Objects and I don't want that!

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
{
    if (i < oldIndexSize)
       newIndex[i] = index[i];
    else
       newIndex[i] = index[i - oldIndexSize];

}
```

Comment: in fact, you want a table of pointers to Bucket<E> elements. `Bucket<E>** index = new (Bucket<E> *)[2];`

Comment: You're starting out wrong. Unless you made a copy and paste error, your first line of code is not an array of pointers, it's just one pointer that you initialise to hold two Buckets. Did you mean `Bucket<E>**`?

Comment: Or, you'd probably be better of with a vector of pointers.

Comment: yes, I'm starting out wrong, I need `Bucket<E>** index = new Bucket<E>*[2];`

Comment: @user1308532: If you really need to use raw pointers, and if you find the double pointer syntax (`Bucket<E>**`) confusing, you may want to use some intermediate `typedef` for better code clarity, e.g. `typedef Bucket<E>* BucketPtr;`, and then allocate with `BucketPtr* index = new BucketPtr[2];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an array of pointers to Bucket-Objects

No, you have a pointer to an array of Bucket objects.  An array of pointers to Bucket objects would look like this:

```
Bucket<E> * index[2];
```

A dynamically allocated array of pointers to bucket objects would be declared like this:

```
Bucket<E> ** index = new Bucket<E>*[N];
```

But what you should probably be using is a vector of shared pointers to bucket objects, like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bucket<E>>> index;
```

Comment: Using `std::shared_ptr` mechanically, without knowing why, and without understanding its problems, is a recipe for disaster.  On the other hand, he should definitely be using `std::vector`, and not be allocating an array of pointers.  (In something like 25 years of C++, I've never yet found a use for `new[]`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It wasn't mechanical.  I do know why, because I read his question.  He wants to share ownership between different elements of his array.

Comment: Where do you see that?  I didn't see anything about ownership.

Comment: @JamesKanze:   I see no other sensible way to interpret his question.  A vector of Bucket objects wouldn't work.  A vector of unique pointers wouldn't work.  The only other possibility I can see is that he has a separate collection of objects and that he would want a vector of dumb pointers acting as references into that collection.  That case seemed unlikely to me, so I ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not re-invent the wheel. Use `std::vector<Bucket<E> >` if you want a resizeable array. If you don't want the buckets to be copied over, you will have to use some indirection. For instance with smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bucket<E>>> index {std::make_shared<Bucket<E>>()/*, ...*/}
```

Comment: @user1308532: In that case, the question should be tagged [tag:homework]. However, especially in University, good code should be chosen over hackish C-like stuff.

Comment: @bitmask: It's better (less overhead, better locality) to use `make_shared` instead of raw `operator new` with `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a Java programer lost in C++ and pointers :D

In modern C++, raw pointers are rarely used. You should prefer **smart pointers** (like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`). This gives several benefits, like helping make your code *exception-safe*, *simplifying* your code (e.g. resources are automatically destructed and released, there is no need to call an explicit `delete`), etc.

> I have an array of pointers to Bucket-Objects
>
> Bucket* index = new Bucket[2];

If the `Bucket` instances you store in the array are not shared, you can use `vector<unique_ptr<Bucket>>`. Else, if there is a shared semantics, you may want to use `vector<shared_ptr<Bucket>>`. You can use `vector::push_back()` method to add new instances of `Bucket`'s to the vector, which will dynamically grow.
If you choose to use `shared_ptr<>` smart pointer, allocate the instances of `Bucket`'s using `make_shared` instead of raw `operator new`.

There is a very interesting series of [STL lessons on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Introduction-to-STL-with-Stephan-T-Lavavej), by the STL maintainer working in Visual C++ Team. You may want to consider [part 1 (sequence containers)](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Introduction-to-STL-with-Stephan-T-Lavavej/) and [part 3 (smart pointers)](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-3-of-n/).

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Array of pointers it will not creat the copy of object it will be only a copy of a pointer and it seems that this code does the thing you want.